# User location sharing

Tags: android, location, sharing

I am developing an android application, which has one module called user location sharing. Though  am able to share the location as a message, its not actually showing any coordinates i.e. latitude or longitude.

Whenever I try to share the location as a message I get "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=0.0.0.0"

Using location manager:

```java
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);


                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);
                        String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality()+",";
                        str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(str));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng,10.2f));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```

I am using menu option format in the toolbar for sharing

```
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.item1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sharing Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" +latitude+","+longitude;
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("text/plain");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share Location Via"));
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location wasn't update so it is initialized by default to 0.0.0.0.

So you must get the last location:
Add these lines

```java
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

Before

```java
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" +latitude+","+longitude;
```

Comment: Did all that, still getting the same error. Any other solution?   Thank anyway

Comment: Did you try to put the code before ```` String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" +latitude+","+longitude; ```` ?

Comment: Ya got it!!. Changed the locationmanager object as i think it was clashing with the other locationmanager objects and re-checked the permissions.        
 Thank You so much :)